# Inverse Laplace transforms

Tags: laplace-transform

Can anyone please help me with taking the inverse Laplace transforms of 3/((s-4)*(s-5)).I have tried splitting the two equations and have received the answer 3exp(9t), which seems to be wrong. Would be grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fractions:

$$\frac {3} {(s-4)(s-5)}= - \frac {3} {(s-4)} + \frac {y} {(s-5)}$$

Find $y$ .

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)